# Git push doesn't ignore files in .gitignore

Tags: git, github

I committed some files that I shouldn't commit.
Then I added these files in .gitignore and I did this:

```
git rm -r --cached somefile
```

and I committed again.

`git status` shows:

`# On branch experiment

nothing to commit, working directory clean`

I do `git ls-files` and these files are not listed.

But when I do `git push origin somebranch`, these files are still being pushed (they're too large to push to github so it fails).

why is this? what should I do?

Comment: you can provide the output of `git status`.:).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The files are still in your git history. From what's in the question the git history is for example:

```
$ git log --oneline
aaaaaaa Update .gitignore and remove big files
bbbbbbb accidentally add big files to repo
ccccccc update foo
ddddddd update bar
```

And pushing fails because of pushing the contents of commit `bbbbbbb`, it doesn't matter that the file is not in your currently checked out version *it's in the project history*.

The above can also be confirmed by checking for the history of a specific file/path:

```
$ git log --all --format=%H -- big.file
aaaaaaa Update .gitignore and remove big files
bbbbbbb accidentally add big files to repo
```

If `big.file` is large enough to prevent pushing to github - you need that list of commits to be empty

### Obliterating a file from history

There are a number of ways to prevent attempting to push `big.file` to the remote, but based on the info in the question the simplest of which is:

```
$ git reset --hard ccccccc
```

This will remove commits `aaaaaaa` and `bbbbbbb` thus there will be no attempt to push `big.file` to the remote.

### The purpose of .gitignore

`.gitignore` files affect *adding* files to the repository, they [do not affect files already in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18829774/git-fetch-and-include-all-gitignore-files). This is the reason that adding files to `.gitignore` has had no effect on 'the problem'.

Comment: What if you made some other changes in commits aaaaaa and bbbbbb that you want to keep? Is there a way to surgically remove the offending big.file without obliterating the rest of your commit history?

Comment: I believe what you wanted was `git rm --cached myUnwantedFile`

Comment: @medley56 that would keep the file in history. Ethan git rebase, editing commits aaaaaa and bbbbbb - there are many existing questions (also, many of which I've answered) for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you have commited the file .
You can cancel the lastest commit bu using:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

And then:

```
git reset filename
```

And then add the file to .gitignore:

or:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged  filename
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions here will work but you will lose other changes in the same commit. If you don't want to lose the other changes in the same commit, and you didn't push the commit yet, you have to change HEAD back to a previous commit, add the changed file and amend:

First find which commit you would like to return to:

```
$ git log --oneline
```

Then, it's needed to checkout another branch because you cannot change the HEAD in the active branch:

```
$ git checkout master
```

Then, change the head of the branch to an older commit:

```
$ git branch -f <branch_name> <commit_id>
```

Then, add the changed file to current commit:

```
$ git add <filename>
```

Then, amend the change into current commit:

```
$ git commit --amend --no-edit
```

That multi-step solution worked out for me to not lose changes and add new changes to a previous commit.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, following @AD7six answer, is to create a new branch with no history, so you can push this branch to the remote server ignoring completely the large file.

You can accomplish this by doing:

```
git checkout --orphan <name_you_choose_for_orphan_branch>
git commit
```

And then push your changes with

```
git push <remote-name> <name_you_choose_for_orphan_branch>
```

Source: [How can I purge all the history and push it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34954852/3998212)

Comment: Basically just repeats what it says at https://stackoverflow.com/a/34954852/341994. This should be a comment containing a link, not an answer.